# Model needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used

Tags: django-models, manytomanyfield

I am unable to save a model in Django with a ManyToManyField while inside Django Admin because I don't know how to create the ID in the database first, and then save the data. It's trying to do both at the same time, but I have to separate the two processes, and I don't know how.

I've gone five full pages deep on Google, and there are tons of answers, but nothing that I can relate to my specific use case.

The error message I get when submitting the form that has the ManyToManyField in it:

```
ValueError: "<Clients: Lowe, Robb>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

Here's the model I'm using:

```html
class BusinessInfo(models.Model):

    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    business_name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50)
    business_address = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50)
    business_city = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50)
    business_state = models.CharField(choices=STATE_SELECT, null=True, blank=True, max_length=50)
    related_person = models.ManyToManyField('Clients', related_name='related_person', null=True, blank=True)
    business_zip = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    business_contact_name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50)
    business_phone = PhoneField(null=True, help_text='Phone Number | <span style="color: red;">Required</span>')
    business_email = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50)
```

And specifically the field I created:

```
    related_person = models.ManyToManyField('Clients', related_name='related_person', null=True, blank=True)
```

I've also attempted to use django-modelcluster to no avail.

I'm pretty new to Django so if anyone can help me out and use explicit code that would help me a great deal. Thank you!

Comment: Can you share your form? Or how you are saving the many-to-many relationship exactly?

Comment: bdbd - I'm using Django Admin, which means that the form is created automatically. My understanding is that I have to override the Save function and specify the order in which items are saved - saving the ID (primary key) for the ManyToManyField first, and then saving the remaining fields.